# How to remove the reference of @using @Model shown on View in MVC5 ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view with the following reference at the top of the view as shown below.

```
@using MVC_Application.ViewModels.SPA;
@Model MainViewModel;
@{
    Layout = null;
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
```

When this view is viewed on a browser I do see the reference shown on browser as **MVC_Application.ViewModels.SPA.MainViewModel MainViewModel;** at the top of the screen and rest of the View is displayed as expected.

Can someone please tell me how to remove this reference when View is viewed on a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use the `model` directive by using an uppercase `M`. That is the instance of the model passed in which is why you see the typename output and then the plain text of `MainViewModel` following it. Simply change your directive to this:

```
@model MainViewModel
```

*Note: The semicolons are not needed*

Bonus: You could also get rid of the `@using` line by specifying the full model namespace (assuming the rest of the view doesn't rely on it):

```
@model MVC_Application.ViewModels.SPA.MainViewModel
```

Comment: Thank you. It fixed my issue.